# How to assign probabilities to sample data points

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-function

I have a list of continuous values that represents a sample of data points observed from my experiment. For instance:

```
myData = [-0.001, 0.0002, -0.015, 0.008]
```

The length of the list is variable, depending of each experiment running. Values range on [-1,1]. The mean length is about 300 elements.

I need assign the probabilities for each element in my list, having into account that the value represents the notion that the higher they are, the more probability they have of being chosen.

I read some similar post, that nears me to the solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772882/picking-a-random-item-based-on-probabilities), where point me out to use a cumulative probabilities approach. In this sense, I have the option of assign the probability of 1 to the max value and 0 to the min value and for the values in the middle assign the probabilities in a descending order, i.e. "using a 'geometric descent' where there is some common ratio to get from one probability to the next" (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2753265/assign-probability-to-each-element-of-a-list-descendingly-and-make-them-sum-as-1)

My question is, should I assign the probabilities following the cdf of my data points? I mean, it is logical to think that the probability for each element in the sample list must be according to the probability distribution of my whole data points and not just apply a ratio between adjacent elements in the sample list?

The image below shows the histogram of data point distribution. Is skewed to the right with a value mean very close to zero.

[image]

In the context of my experiment, that is graph analytics, every data point is the "force" with it each node is linked to its neighbors. Every node can have multiple attributes. My objective is to use this force to predict what attribute is more likely to be present in a random node picked up from the whole graph, one that we don't know about his attributes. So, every element of my list above represent one attribute present in the neighbor nodes of the random one, and his value is the sum of the forces from all nodes where the attribute is present. The intuition behind this is the higher the sum of forces for an attribute, the more probable is that attribute is present in the random node.

Comment: (1) Your data are *left* skewed, not right skewed. (2) This procedure is called *density estimation.* There are a huge number of ways to go about it, depending on what you know or assume about the data generation process.  (3) Often, density estimation is not the ultimate objective: it's a means to an end.  Almost as often, it's not necessary.  Could you therefore share with us some information about *why* you want to do this?

Comment: There's no one "correct" answer, different probability weightings might be appropriate for different purposes. You could have a near-uniform distribution of probabilities, or a strong linear change, or an exponential weighting that highly upweights the highest values, etc. None of those are inherently "best". What do you want the weighting to look like?

Comment: I have updated my question at the end, adding the context of my experiment.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your comment on skewed.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie good question. My short answer is I don't know. But, considering the objective of my experiment where the probability helps me to predict if an attribute is present or not in the random node, the weighting should output probabilities of uncertainty for values near to the mean, and false or true while the values move away from that mean towards the minimum and maximum decreasing or increasing respectively, faster when they are near to the boundaries. Sounds like a gaussian, right? I'm speculating, I fear.